# array placement changes output?

Tags: javascript

If `RegExp` is at the end of the array, the output returns a value of object. But if it's anywhere else in the array it returns `RegExp`. Why is that?

```
var val_type = [Function, Boolean, Number, String,  Object, RegExp];
// Any where else returns value of RegExp, but why not at the end?
function type(arg) {
    if(typeof arg === "object" || typeof arg === "function") {
        for(var i = 0; i < val_type.length; i++) {
            if (arg instanceof val_type[i]) {
                return val_type[i];
            } 
        }
    }   
    return typeof arg;
}
alert(val_type(/j/i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I beg to differ: This occurs not simply when `RegExp` is at the end of the array; this happens whenever `Object` comes before `RegExp`. Also, the same happens for `Function`.

This is because all functions, arrays, and regular expressions inherit from `Object`. Although `Object` might not be their constructor, their constructors inherit from `Object` and thus so do they and thus they are considered instances of it by the `instanceof` operator.

To fix this, check the `.constructor` property instead of `instanceof`. Sometimes, `instanceof` can be used to check if an object simply inherits from a constructor (i.e. checking if a `Node` inherits from `Element` to see if it is an element), but other times, we want to be more strict, so we use the `.constructor` property:

```
var val_type = [Function, Boolean, Number, String,  Object, RegExp, Array]; //Don't forget Array!
function type(arg) {
    if(typeof arg === "object" || typeof arg === "function") {
        for(var i = 0; i < val_type.length; i++) {
            if (arg.constructor == val_type[i]) {
                return val_type[i]; //_Now_ it returns the correct constructor...
            } 
        }
    }   
    //...unless it's a primitive type, in which case, we just use typeof
    return typeof arg;
}
alert(type(/j/i));
```